# What type of value is send by the input's value attribute in HTML

Tags: html

> `<input type="text" value="">`

what value type is send by the input value attribute, and if I explicitly specified the value attribute in the input tag so which one will go,
the one that I entered or the one that i explicitly specified.

And can I change the type of the value from String to Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` of an input determines what UI is presented to the user and may also limit what can be entered into the input. (e.g. supporting browsers will not allow the user to enter a letter into an input with `type="number"`).

The `value` attribute specifies the *default* value for the input.

If the value is changed either by the user typing something into the field or JavaScript modifying the `value` *property* then the default value no longer has any significance.

If the `value` *attribute* is changed by JavaScript then it will update the current value iff the current value has not been changed as per the previous paragraph.

If the `type` is changed with JavaScript to one that makes the current value invalid, it will be "fixed" by the browser.

When the form is submitted, the data will be encoded using either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encodings. Neither of these distinguish between different kinds of data, so the server will receive only a text representation of the data (even if `type="number"`).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally value you specified in **input tag** is the default value for your input box. However if you changed explicitly then it will get overridden. So the value sent to the server/javascript will be the recent value of text-field.
   And if you want to convert String to Integer, then it got different implementation depends on which language you are parsing that String. I am considering it in JavaScript. So to convert it into the Number you can use **parseInt(String)** from JavaScript.

Here what i did:

```
 [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/f6bwjsuh/
```

Answer (score 0):

From 
[enter link description here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html)

**The input element with a type attribute whose value is "text" represents a one-line plain text edit control for the input element’s value.**

So usually backend frameworks like spring do the job of parsing in suitable type.